# Slam and Vision (good resources)?

Tags: kalman-filter, slam, ekf

I would like to know if there is a good source that combines Slam problem with vision. From mathematical perspective, there are numerous resources that handle SLAM ,however, I didn't find a good source that focuses on slam and vision.

Comment: Here's one link: https://www.willowgarage.com/blog/2010/09/14/visual-slam-ros although I'm concerned that this question is a little overly broad.  Is there a particular part of implementing SLAM through your vision system that you're stuck on?

Comment: @Ian, I think the question is clear. I know SLAM but I want to know the methods from a technical perspective to discover and move the robot in computer vision. I only mentioned SLAM to reduce the number of topics in computer vision.

Comment: The question is broad in the sense that it doesn't say what makes a given resource "good" for your purposes.  Why aren't the results of a google search for `visual slam` good enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Someuseful resources*

*Video lecture* : [Monocular SLAM and Real-Time Scene Perception](http://videolectures.net/bmvc2012_davison_scene_perception/)

*Lecture slides from TU-Dresden* [Vision-based SLAM lecture](http://www.wv.inf.tu-dresden.de/~wiki/Robotics/Tutorials/SLAM-Summer-2006/Lectures/Lacroix/lacroix-visionSLAM.pdf)

*Lecture from Bristol University (some links dead)* : [Visual SLAM tutorial](http://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/Research/Vision/Resources/bmvctutorial/)

Comment: wow these are very nice videos. Thank you so much. Definitely it will be the good answer. Google didn't give me these results. lol

Comment: @CroCo yup lol :)